# What is a B* tree and how does it differ from a B tree and a B+ tree?

Tags: b-tree, b-plus-tree

I can't seem to find a solid answer of what B* tree is. I am aware that a B tree stores both keys and data in its internal and leaf nodes and B+ tree stores keys in its interior nodes and data in its leaf nodes but how is B* tree different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Variants):

> The B*-tree balances more neighboring internal nodes to keep the
>   internal nodes more densely packed (Comer 1979, p. 129). This variant
>   requires non-root nodes to be at least 2/3 full instead of 1/2 (Knuth
>   1998, p. 488). To maintain this, instead of immediately splitting up a
>   node when it gets full, its keys are shared with a node next to it.
>   When both nodes are full, then the two nodes are split into three. The
>   act of deleting nodes is somewhat more complex than inserting however.